# SonarQube: PL/SQL rules duplicated

Tags: sonarqube

In my SonarQube instance, I have the rule "Variables should not be shadowed" duplicated.

The both are actrived and only one reports Issues.
So I deactivated the one that report nothing but I wonder why there are similar rules.

Comment: Are you sure they are really duplicates? Some rules look exactly the same but apply to different languages/plugins.

Comment: Yes they are linked to PL/SQL plugin. I filtered on PL/SQL rules only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARPLSQL-636). It should be fixed in the next version of SonarPLSQL.